# Not enough memory WinAPI

Tags: winapi

I would like some help because i am lock on this problem during few days.

I looking for on google and try to understand what is dwMaximumSizeHigh and dwMaximumSizeLow.

I read some documentation about this parameters but i don't really understand what is it.

I wrote a code

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void MappingOpen(PCWSTR lpFileName)
{
  HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(lpFileName, FILE_GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

  if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    FILE_STANDARD_INFO fsi;
    if (GetFileInformationByHandleEx(hFile, FileStandardInfo, &fsi, sizeof(fsi)))
    {
        HANDLE hSection = CreateFileMappingW(hFile, 0, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 1, 0);
        if (hSection == NULL)
        {
            DWORD error_code = GetLastError();
            printf("The error code is %lu",error_code);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("The create file mapping work ");
            CloseHandle(hSection);
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hFile);
}else
 {
    printf("Cannot be open");
 }
}
```

Even if i add 0 to dwMaximumSizeHigh and 0 dwMaximumSizeHigh i got another error (ERROR_FILE_INVALID).

Thanks you very much

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-createfilemappingw): *"An attempt to map a file with a length of 0 (zero) fails with an error code of `ERROR_FILE_INVALID`. Applications should test for files with a length of 0 (zero) and reject those files."*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

dwMaximumSizeHigh and dwMaxsimumSizeLow are parts of the same Value ...

its a 64-Bit value in 32-Bit parts.. the High and Low-parts..

|  32bit (high)  |  32bit (low) |

Maybe that helps to understand.

it is explained here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-createfilemappingw?redirectedfrom=MSDN (4th and 5th Parameter)